locality of affine connection
Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $\nabla:\,\mathfrak X(M)\times \mathfrak X(M)\longrightarrow\mathfrak X(M)$ be an affine connection. Let $U\subset M$ be a neighborhood of $p\in M$. Suppose $X=\widetilde X$ and $Y=\widetilde Y$ on $U$. I wonder if $\nabla_XY\Big|_p=\nabla_{\widetilde X}{\widetilde Y}\Big|_p$ ?
May you give me some guildance and hints about this ? Thanks.

There are two general principles here. The first is that you have $C^{\infty}(M)$-linearity in the lower slot, so this implies (by the “tensor characterization lemma”) that in the lower slot only the tangent vector $X_p$ at the point $p$ matters. Second, in the $Y$ slot, you have a product rule; this implies locality (use bump functions). Prove these two lemmas separately.

And if this hint isnt enough, then you need to search the site more carefully because I’ve answered this (in a few variants) a few times at various levels of generality, and so have others. And finally, this is a standard result which you can find in for example, Lee’s book.

@peek-a-boo do I need to use the expression $X_p=\sum X_i\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} $ for this proof ?

Just google what I suggested.

Write everything in local coordinates.

@peek-a-boo I see it's quite easy to solve if one uses the bump function. My question is, why bump function, since it's kind of a trick, and is there other ways without using such trick ?

it’s not just a “trick”. It is a fundamental use of $C^{\infty}$-linearity and how that interacts with the product rule. Note that your assumptions are very limited: you’re only assuming $C^{\infty}$-linearity and a product rule. A-priori, it is surprising that this implies locality. But, the whole point of bump functions is to localize things suitably (this can mean various things in various contexts). So I wouldn’t say it’s just a “trick”. It’s a very crucial fact about analysis, and I’d suggest you really make sure your understand and appreciate it in full.
